# fatal: repository not found

Tags: reactjs, git, github, repository

I had tried to push changes, but I got `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git/' not found` error. I tried

```
$ git credential-manager uninstall
$ git credential-managerinstall
```

this didn't work too. Tried deleting all credential manager, didn't work too.
Then deleted the old repository, created new and tried to pull it, again didn't work.
Here is my homepage script

> "homepage": "https://charyyev2000.github.io/Portfolio-React",

Could anyone help me, please? What do I do wrong?

> Note: My repository is public

Comment: What does your `git remote -v` look like?

Comment: You do know that GitHub no longer accept passwords for `git push`, right? You must use a Personal Access Token instead, as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). Alternatively, you can use ssh instead of https.

Comment: `origin  https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git (fetch)`
`origin  https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git (push)` looks like this.